# iframe loads parent instead child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load my page in iframe .

It loads and works fine untill I maximize page.

As soon as I press fullscreen button it actually load parent frame instead of current frame. Also keeps tooltip as it is. I have to hide tooltip it manually.

for instance,

step 1 ----->  I open google page
step 2 ----->  search "something" and Click suggested search url in page

step 3 ----->  my iframe loads search URL and display.

step 4 ----->  then I move my mouse over maximize button, and click it, 
This time it loads google home page instead of search URL.

Please find my code below.
Any suggestion please.

```
onFullscreen: function(e) {
   $(this).tooltip('hide');
   if( $('#jarviswidget-fullscreen-mode').height() ){
        $('#iframeid' ).attr('height', $('#jarviswidget-fullscreen-mode').height() - 70 );
   } else {
         //$('#iframeid' ).attr('height', $('#' + '$widget->id' + '_container').height() - 254 );
         $('#iframeid' ).attr('height', origin );
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I alias my box name, i mean server address so that domain name will be same as iframe src. This way you can fool your browser and stop violating same origin policy.
You can read href value from location object now.

```
onLoad = ' console.log(this.contentWindow.location.href);'
```